# Как корректно повысить уровень звука?

Tags: android, service

Есть МП. При определенных условиях на телефоне отсылается `Broadcast`, в следствии чего `BroadcastReceiver` МП его ловит и запускает `Service` единственной целью которого является проигрывание звука нотификации.

Собственно метод:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags, final int startId) {

        Timber.i("beeeep!..");

        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        Uri notifyUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, notifyUri);

        int ringtoneStreamType = ringtone.getStreamType();
        int value = audioManager.getStreamVolume(ringtoneStreamType);
        int maxValue = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(ringtoneStreamType);
        Timber.i("current value: %d, max value: %d", value, maxValue);
        if (value < maxValue) {
            //set max value
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(ringtoneStreamType,
                    maxValue,
                    0);
        }

        ringtone.play();

//        audioManager.setStreamVolume(ringtoneStreamType,
//                value,
//                0);

        stopSelf();

        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

Возникает 2 проблемы:

1) Метод `getStreamType` deprecated

2) Судя по всему метод который я закомментил возвращает исходное состояние уровня звука до того как проиграется рингтон, хотел бы понять как узнать завершился ли рингтон и только после этого вернуть исходное состояние

Comment: Извините за глупый вопрос, но что такое МП?)

Comment: Мобильное приложение, App...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил следующим образом.

```
public void beep() {

        Timber.i("beeeep!..");

        Uri notifyUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);

        try {
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, notifyUri);
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
            mMediaPlayer.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mMediaPlayer.release();
                stopSelf();
            }
        });

    }
```